# Xamarin ListView Binding

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm creating a ListView with a DataTemplate in code. I'm getting the text values to bind to from a name/paired dictionary that in turn gets them from a JSON file via a service. The problem I can't figure out is how to do the binding. In a perfect world I'd just create a DataTable from the same name/paired dictionary and bind the ListView to that in code, but from what I'm reading you can't bind a DataTable to a ListView so what other options do I have? I could create a class with let's say X properties and just say we are limited to dynamically creating X properties to bind to, but that seems a bit cheesy.

The ultimate idea is that we can change what is displayed by changing the JSON it reads from a service and not have to change the code.

Any other suggestions?

Code to add the listview:

```cs
private void PopulateCases()
    {
        var caseStackLayout = new StackLayout{Padding = 8};            
        var caseGrid = new Grid();

        var cases = _viewModel.GridCases();
        var loopCt = 1;
        foreach (var c in cases)
        {
            if (loopCt == 1)
            {
                var headerLabel = new Label { FontSize = 18, TextColor = Color.Blue };
                AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(headerLabel, new Rectangle(.25f, .25f, 400f, 40f));
                headerLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, c.FieldName, BindingMode.Default, null, c.Label + " {0:N}");
                //headerLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, c.FieldName);
                caseStackLayout.Children.Add(headerLabel);                    
            }
            else
            {
                caseGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
                caseGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Auto) });
                var caseLabel = new Label { FontSize = 14, TextColor = Color.Gray };
                caseLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, c.FieldName, BindingMode.Default, null, c.Label + " {0:N}");
                var column = 0;
                if (loopCt % 2 == 0)
                {
                    column = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    column = 0;
                }
                caseGrid.Children.Add(caseLabel, column, loopCt);
            }
            loopCt++;
        }
        caseStackLayout.Children.Add(caseGrid);            
        var myViewCell = new ViewCell { View = caseStackLayout };
        var caseDataTemplate = new DataTemplate( ()=> { return myViewCell; } );

        var caseSearchBar = new SearchBar();
        caseSearchBar.SetBinding(SearchBar.PlaceholderProperty, "SearchTitle");
        caseSearchBar.SetBinding(SearchBar.TextProperty, "SearchValue");
        caseSearchBar.SearchButtonPressed += DoSearch;

        var casesListView = new ListView
        {                
            ItemTemplate = caseDataTemplate,
            Header = caseSearchBar,             
            HasUnevenRows = true
        };
        casesListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Cases");
        casesListView.ItemTapped += Handle_ItemTapped;            
        myCases.Children.Add(casesListView);
    }

    async void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item == null)
            return;
        await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new BusyPopup("Getting Case Documents..."));
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DocumentListView((AgriPolicy)e.Item));
        await Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync();
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

Here is the JSON which contains other data too but the gridCases is what this is going for (note I removed the binary images as it was too much to paste):

```js
{
    "caseSearchTypes": [
        {
            "searchName": "Cases",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "searchFields": [
                {
                    "comparator": "like",
                    "displayName": "Insured Name",
                    "fieldName": "InsuredName",
                    "icon": "##",
                    "position": 1,
                    "maxResults": 50,
                    "where": [
                        {
                            "name": "Hidden",
                            "value": "true",
                            "comparator": "!="
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "BUID",
                            "value": "002",
                            "comparator": "="
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "comparator": "ends with",
                    "displayName": "Customer Number",
                    "fieldName": "CustomerNumber",
                    "icon": "##",
                    "position": 2,
                    "maxResults": 50,
                    "where": [
                        {
                            "name": "Hidden",
                            "value": "true",
                            "comparator": "!="
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "BUID",
                            "value": "002",
                            "comparator": "="
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "comparator": "=",
                    "displayName": "Submission ID",
                    "fieldName": "SubmissionID",
                    "icon": "##",
                    "position": 3,
                    "maxResults": 50,
                    "where": [
                        {
                            "name": "Hidden",
                            "value": "true",
                            "comparator": "!="
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "BUID",
                            "value": "002",
                            "comparator": "="
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "comparator": "=",
                    "displayName": "Policy Number",
                    "fieldName": "PolicyNumber",
                    "icon": "##",
                    "position": 4,
                    "where": [
                        {
                            "name": "Hidden",
                            "value": "true",
                            "comparator": "!="
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "BUID",
                            "value": "002",
                            "comparator": "="
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "gridCases": [
                {
                    "label": "",
                    "fieldName": "InsuredName",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "row": 0,
                    "column": -1
                },
                {
                    "label": "",
                    "fieldName": "Symbol",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "row": 1,
                    "column": 0,
                    "concatenate": [
                        {
                            "label": "",
                            "fieldName": "PolicyNumber",
                            "dataType": "String",
                            "Position": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": "Customer #: ",
                    "fieldName": "CustomerNumber",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "row": 1,
                    "column": 1
                },
                {
                    "label": "",
                    "fieldName": "PolicyEffectiveDate",
                    "dataType": "DateTime",
                    "row": 2,
                    "column": 0,
                    "concatenate": [
                        {
                            "label": " - ",
                            "fieldName": "",
                            "dataType": "",
                            "Position": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "",
                            "fieldName": "PolicyExpirationDate",
                            "dataType": "",
                            "Position": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": "Submission #: ",
                    "fieldName": "SubmissionID",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "row": 1,
                    "column": 1
                }
            ],
            "selectCases": [
                {
                    "field": "CustomerNumber"
                },
                {
                    "field": "Symbol"
                },
                {
                    "field": "PolicyNumber"
                },
                {
                    "field": "DOCEX_Status"
                },
                {
                    "field": "InsuredName"
                },
                {
                    "field": "DBA"
                },
                {
                    "field": "SubmissionID"
                },
                {
                    "field": "PolicyEffectiveDate"
                },
                {
                    "field": "PolicyExpirationDate"
                },
                {
                    "field": "ProducerName"
                },
                {
                    "field": "ProducerCode"
                },
                {
                    "field": "DOCEX_UnderwriterName"
                },
                {
                    "field": "Id"
                }
            ],
            "searchCases": [
                {
                    "searchName": "Policy",
                    "objectType": "PIM_Policy",
                    "maxResults": 50,
                    "filters": [
                        {
                            "name": "CustomerNumber",
                            "value": "$CustomerNumber",
                            "comparator": "like"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "InsuredName",
                            "value": "$InsuredName",
                            "comparator": "like"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "PolicyNumber",
                            "value": "$PolicyNumber",
                            "comparator": "="
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "SubmissionID",
                            "value": "$SubmissionID",
                            "comparator": "="
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Hidden",
                            "value": "true",
                            "comparator": "!="
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "BUID",
                            "value": "003",
                            "comparator": "="
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images!!

Comment: and it would help if you provided a sample of the json you are working with

Comment: Updates made.  Thx.

Comment: I can convert the gridCases json into a strongly typed class without using a Dictionary.

Comment: GridCases is a strongly typed class which is how the JSON is read in and then that class is iterated over in the for loop adding the Label controls to the DataTemplate.  The problem is with the line:

casesListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Cases");

We need this to be bound to something we can Dynamically create and populate such as a DataTable.

Comment: I thought I had a solution using ExpandoObject but that doesn't work with iOS as I found out the hard way https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2921. I'm about to head a different direction as I don't think this can be done.

Comment: What do you mean by bound to something we can Dynamically create and populate such as a DataTable.? You can change the data in gridCases so that the value of properties gridCases will be updated, then the binding will work and label.text will also be updated.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I'm obviously not asking my question well and for that I apologize.  The JSON is not the data - the JSON simply tells me what FieldName I need to pull the data from.  This except from an OReilly book explains what I want to do https://www.oreilly.com/content/building-c-objects-dynamically/ Unfortunately as I mentioned above the ExpandoObject does not appear to work with iOS so I can find no way of dynamically creating what I need to bind too.

Comment: Yeah, there is a limitation in iOS and you can not make it work.